# Rails: create action for associated Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Pretty basic Rails question I assume but I can't figure out the simplicity of Rails.

My simple goal is to have a user submit a form indicating the amount of a donation, and have that donation linked to the user. I'm having trouble with the `create` action in the `donations_controller.rb`

I have a `User.rb` model and a `Donation.rb` model. The User.rb `has_one :donation` and Donation.rb `belongs_to :user`. I am also using Devise so I have the `current_user` method.

My donation table looks like this

```
class CreateDonations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :donations do |t|
      t.integer :amount
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :donations, [:user_id, :created_at]
  end
end
```

The `_form.html.erb` for the `donations_controller.rb` looks like this

```
<%= form_for @donation do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.number_field :amount %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The `create` action in donations_controller.rb looks like this

```
def create
    @donation  = current_user.donation.build(params[:donation])
    if @donation.save
      flash[:success] = "Donation"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'home/index'
    end
  end
```

I'm getting this error message when I submit the form.

```
NoMethodError in DonationsController#create

undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method for building the has_one association is `current_user.build_donation(params[:donation])`